# Awk: compare two files

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I have a file1.txt

```
USA Joe 123.123.123
Russia Marry 458.786.892
Canada Greg 151.844.165
Latvia Grace 125.895.688
```

and file2.txt

```
1 123.123.123
2 151.844.165
3 465.879.515
```

and I want to create a new file `result.txt` where I print my only those lines that adresses (xxx.xxx.xxx) are both  in file1 and file2 so my result should be

```
USA Joe 123.123.123
Canada Greg 151.844.165
```

I need to use awk, but how I need to use it for both files?

Comment: Weird requirement. Why necessarily *awk*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2];next};$NF in a' file2.txt file1.txt > result.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps like this:

```
join -1 3 -2 2 <(sort -k 3 file1.txt) <(sort -k 2 file2.txt) | awk '{ print $2, $3, $1 }'
```

This:

- doesn't read any file entirely in memory
- still uses `awk(1)` ;)